# php 2d array search

Tags: php, search, associative-array

I have an array

```
$user['123'][]= 2/2/2012;
$user['123'][]= 2/3/2012;
$user['123'][]= 2/4/2012;
  ['123'] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2/2/2012
        [1] => 2/3/2012
        [2] => 2/4/2012
    )
```

What I want to do , is to check whether $var=2/3/2012 is in the array or not,

I tried using in_array , it didnt work
any solution would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
<?php

$user['123'][]= '2/2/2012';
$user['123'][]= '2/3/2012';
$user['123'][]= '2/4/2012';

function dateIn2DArray($date, $haystack) {
  foreach($haystack as $dates) {
    if (in_array($date, $dates)) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

var_dump(dateIn2DArray('2/2/2012', $user)); // true
var_dump(dateIn2DArray('2/2/2013', $user)); // false
```

The function loops over the elements in the array searching it's children for the date.

Comment: This works good, but what if I have $user['232'][] , and I want to search for that specific userID.  , like im trying to pass the userID also  if(dateIn2DArray('2/2/2012', $user['123']))
{
    echo 'trueo';
} , gives me an array

Answer (score 0):

```
$is_in_array = false;
foreach ($user as $sub_array){
    if (in_array("2/3/2012", $sub_array)){
        $is_in_array = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

The point is that `in_array` works for one-dimensional arrays, so you have to check separately in each of the sub arrays.

Answer (score 0):

check link
`http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php`

`$user['123'][]= '2/2/2012';`

`$user['123'][]= '2/3/2012';`

`$user['123'][]= '2/4/2012';`

`$var='2/3/2012';`

`echo in_array($var, $user['123']);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive PHP function I wrote to search for a value in depth :

```
function in_array_recursive($needle, $haystack){
    if (in_array($needle, $haystack)) return true;
    else{
          foreach ($haystack as $key=>$value){
            if (is_array($haystack[$key])) {
                return in_array_recursive($needle, $haystack[$key]);
                }
          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

The call:

```
 echo in_array_recursive($item, $arr);
```